# Java Index Out Of Bounds Error on Pascal Triangle

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to create a Pascal Triangle and when I run the code, it gives me an Array out Of Bounds Error. Please Help. I guess I have used a good logic but am unable to get the result.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Question_4
 {
 public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException
  {
      System.out.println("Enter the value of N");
      InputStreamReader x = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
      BufferedReader y = new BufferedReader (x);
      int n = Integer.parseInt (y.readLine ());
      int ar [] [] = new int [n] [(2*n)-1];
      int previous = 0;
      int next = 0;
      int se = 0;
      for (int row = 0 ; row<n ; row++)
       {
         se = (n - row) - 1;
         for (int column = 0 ; column < ((2*n)-1) ; column ++)
          {
              try
               {
                 previous = ar [row-1] [column+1];
                 next = ar [row-1] [column +3];
                }
              finally
               {
                 if (column < se)
                      ar [row] [column] = 0;
                 else if (column > (n-se))
                      ar [row] [column] = 0;
                 else if (row == 0 || row == 1)
                      ar [row] [column] = 1;
                 else
                      ar [row] [column] = (previous + next);
                }
            }
        }
      for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j<((2*n)-1);j++)
            System.out.print (ar [i] [j]);
           System.out.println ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a very good substitute for a debugger.  What line throws the exception?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  What logic led it to that error?  Which index are you trying to reference that doesn't exist?  Why are you trying to reference it?  Step through the code in a debugger, nobody here is going to do that for you.  Also, why on earth do you have that `try/finally` construct?  Whatever you're doing in the `finally` block doesn't look like code that belongs in a `finally` block, especially if that's where the exception is happening...

Comment: You should provide some information about where is that exception thrown. Nevertheless, I guess wrong lines are `previous = ar [row-1] [column+1];` and `ar [row-1] [column +3];`, because when  `column` takes `(2*n)-2`, `ar[row][(2*n)-1]` does is out of bounds. Even more `column + 3`

Answer (score 0):

The problem within the this line:

```
previous = ar [row-1] [column+1];
```

At the first time of the outer loop, the row value is `0`, so `0 - 1` is `-1`, which is invalid position the array.

Answer (score 0):

You declared this array:

```
int ar [] [] = new int [n] [(2*n)-1];
```

Then you have this loop:

```
for (int column = 0 ; column < ((2*n)-1) ; column ++)
```

Which means that column will at some point be equal to the index of the last cell in ar[][]. And in your loop you call:

```
previous = ar [row-1] [column+1];
next = ar [row-1] [column +3];
```

That is why you get indexOutOfBoundsException.